# Django or python version issue: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'database'

Tags: python-3.x, django, module

when i try to start my Django project i get this error which i am unable to solve:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'database'
```

The error stack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/olw/candidatis/database-rest/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/olw/candidatis/database-rest/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 455, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/home/olw/candidatis/database-rest/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 487, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/home/olw/candidatis/database-rest/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/home/olw/candidatis/database-rest/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/caches.py", line 17, in check_default_cache_is_configured
    if DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS not in settings.CACHES:
  File "/home/olw/candidatis/database-rest/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 87, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/olw/candidatis/database-rest/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 74, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/olw/candidatis/database-rest/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 183, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'database'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/olw/candidatis/database-rest/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/olw/candidatis/database-rest/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/olw/candidatis/database-rest/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/olw/candidatis/database-rest/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/olw/candidatis/database-rest/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 427, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/home/olw/candidatis/database-rest/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 212, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "/home/olw/candidatis/database-rest/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 73, in __iter__
    return iter(self.settings)
  File "/home/olw/candidatis/database-rest/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/olw/candidatis/database-rest/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 45, in settings
    self._settings = self.configure_settings(self._settings)
  File "/home/olw/candidatis/database-rest/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 148, in configure_settings
    databases = super().configure_settings(databases)
  File "/home/olw/candidatis/database-rest/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 50, in configure_settings
    settings = getattr(django_settings, self.settings_name)
  File "/home/olw/candidatis/database-rest/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 87, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/olw/candidatis/database-rest/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 74, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/olw/candidatis/database-rest/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 183, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'database'
```

I already tried to install the `databases` package (This is the recommended answer you almost find anywhere)

Trying to make sense out of the stack trace it seems that python itself cannot import this module (So there is no issue in my code or something...).

My installed packages:

[image]

The python version i am using is `Python 3.10.5`

Anybody any idea ?

**UPDATE APPS LIST**

Here is my installed apps list ->

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "django.contrib.admindocs.urls",
    "rest",
    "rest_framework",
    "custom_db_logger",
]
```

Comment: Did you put `databases` in your installed_apps list? It's looking for `database` without the `s`

Comment: In my installed apps ? Why in my installed apps ? What should i put there ?

Comment: can you also put ```INSTALLED_APPS``` list from your settings.py?